# How to load two ResourceBundles and inject them separately

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am using Spring for loading localized resource bundles into my application. Here is what I have done.

```
<bean id="systemMessages" class="o.s.c.s.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
   <property name="basename" value="locale/system"> 
</bean>

<bean id="clientMessages" class="o.s.c.s.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
   <property name="basename" value="locale/client"> 
</bean>
```

I want to load messages based on the locale in my controller, and I tried both these ways below

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("clientMessages")
ResourceBundleMessageSource clientMessages;

@Resource(name="systemMessages")
ResourceBundleMessageSource systemMessages;
```

**EDIT**

The application is a JAXRS application and the injection is being tried in a Global Exception Mapper. From the comments I now understand that this class would have been created by the JAXRS container and not Spring ( Code below). How to let Spring know that this injection must work?

```
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;

//other imports

public class GlobalWebApplicationException extends WebApplicationException{
   private String systemMessage;
   private String clientMessage;

   //Autowire the multiple resourcebundles

   public GlobalWebApplicationException (String key, Locale locale) {
       // this is where I want to use the injected object fetch the property
   }

   public doSomething(){
       // Business Logic
   }

}
```

But the injection is not happening and I am getting an NPE. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need 2 resource bundles, just load them in a single bundle...

Comment: Both of them have same property keys. And delivers different purpose. Good point, but this separation is needed. Is it possible?

Comment: Ofcourse but for starters don't use `ResourceBundleMessageSource` as the type for wiring but `MessageSource` next it cannot be `null` because spring will fail if it cannot satisfy dependencies. So you either don't have annotation processing enabled or you are creating new instances of the class containing the 2 references, yourself instead of a spring managed instance.

Comment: Thank you. So i have an edit. And the class is being managed by JAXRS container I guess, not spring. So how do i let spring know about this class? I tried annotation such as Inject, Named, Component, Service etc.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have figured out where the problem is. The injection was not happening because the class was not a Spring Managed Bean. You may post the answer, and I can happily accept it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Spring and having it do auto wiring using annotations the fields cannot be `null`. The dependencies need to be satisfied on startup of the application. If that doesn't happen there can be 1 of 2 things wrong

1. You haven't enabled annotation processing
2. You aren't using a spring managed bean but are creating instances yourself

For the first option add `<context:annotation-config />` to your application context, or if you want to do component scanning add `<context:component-scan />` the latter already implies annotation processing.

For the second option you need to make your bean a spring managed bean and use that instead of creating new instances yourself.